# Is there a way to aggregate by time on xts regardless the date

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to split by hour/time without having the date affecting the results, I'm using an xts object indexed by date and time

When i'm using split by hour I get the results but within the date, and I wish to Ignore the date and only get it by time, tried to strip the date and get back to posixct, but none helped, I also tried using period.apply with endpoint but it's the same results.

```
lapply(split(temp[,"GROSS"] , f = "hour"), FUN = cumsum)
[[1]]
                    GROSS
2018-10-12 09:46:38 "11" 

[[2]]
                    GROSS 
2018-10-12 10:04:08 "-4"  
2018-10-12 10:23:58 "5.2" 
2018-10-12 10:24:08 "-1.1"

[[3]]
                    GROSS 
2018-10-15 09:35:46 "20.7"

[[4]]
                    GROSS 
2018-10-17 09:30:56 "-7.2"

[[5]]
                    GROSS 
2018-10-17 10:44:48 "13.5"
```

I expect to get the results accumulated by hour without the date.

Comment: please provide an example of your data with `dput(head(temp[,"GROSS"]))`

Comment: > dput(head(temp[,"GROSS"]))
structure(c("  11.00", "  -4.00", "   9.20", "  -6.30", "  20.70", 
"  -7.20"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1539337598, 
1539338648, 1539339838, 1539339848, 1539596146, 1539768656), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "GROSS"))  @shs

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with date, time or datetime variables the `lubridate` package is really useful.

```r
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

df_ts <- structure(
  c(" 11.00", " -4.00", " 9.20", " -6.30", " 20.70", " -7.20"), 
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), 
  tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), 
  .indexTZ = "UTC", 
  tzone = "UTC", 
  index = structure(c(1539337598, 1539338648, 1539339838, 1539339848, 1539596146, 1539768656), 
                    tzone = "UTC", 
                    tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), 
  .Dim = c(6L, 1L), 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, "GROSS"))

lapply(split(df_ts, 
             f = hour(as_datetime(attr(df_ts, "index")))), 
       FUN = cumsum)
```